# TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have the following basic tensorflow app.  It gives me the error upon execution:

`TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>`

And tensorboard says:  `"No scalar data was found."`

I'm guessing one or all of `square, power, sqrt, final_sum` should be added explicitly to the summary, but I don't know how to do that.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(6, name='constant_a')
b = tf.constant(3, name='constant_b')
c = tf.constant(10, name='constant_c')
d = tf.constant(5.0, name='constant_d')

mul = tf.multiply(a,b, name='mul')

square = tf.square(a, name="square_a")
power = tf.pow(b, c, name="pow_b_c")
sqrt = tf.sqrt(d, name="sqrt_d")

final_sum = tf.add_n([square, power, tf.to_int32(sqrt)], name="final_sum")

sess = tf.Session()

print("Square of a: ", sess.run(square))
print("power of b, c: ", sess.run(power))
print("Square root of of d: ", sess.run(sqrt))

print("Final sum of square, power, and square root: ", sess.run(final_sum))


writer =  tf.summary.FileWriter('./m2_example2', sess.graph)

# Creates a TensorFlow tensor that includes information from all summaries
# defined in the current graph.
summary_t = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Computes the current value of all summaries in the current graph.
summary_val = sess.run(summary_t)

writer.add_summary(summary_val)

writer.close()
sess.close()
```